# Getting entire POST response in one line

Tags: java, post, bufferedreader

I've modified the following code from an example on the internet. Currently it POSTs and returns the response line by line. How can I modify the code so it returns the entire response  in one line, so I can parse it more easily.

```
static void updateIp() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String urlParameters = "name=sub&a=rec_edit&id=9001";
    URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    BufferedReader reader;
    try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream())) {
        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    reader.close(); 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think u just need to change System.out.println(line);
 to             System.out.print(line);

Comment: @JunedAhsan Does that just print it on one line? I'm looking to `return` the response, and if I return it, it seems to only return the first line. I shouldn't have left the `System.out.println(line)` in there because I want to return the response, not print it. Could you give me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't determine how many lines the URL response will be over, so you need to join them all together yourself in one line using `StringBuilder`:

```
static void updateIp() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String urlParameters = "name=sub&a=rec_edit&id=9001";
    URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    BufferedReader reader;
    try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream())) {
        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        StringBuilder urlResponse = new StringBuilder();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            urlResponse.append(line);
        }
        String response = urlResponse.toString();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    reader.close(); 
}
```

The `response` string variable will now contain all the output in a single line.